# Add different version of class for mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I was editing a Wordpress theme and I added a content box to Bootstrap's `<div class="well">`. I had to remove the content box's `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` because while on desktop there was a lot of space in the contentbox after the content box was displayed. While the removal of padding and margin works well on desktop, it overflows on mobile. The image as follows:-
[image]

On PC, it looks like this :-
[image]

Anyways, this is the content box that comes inside `<div class='well'>`:

```
.site-content article {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    padding-bottom:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add padding-bottom with media queries in your css :

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

 Your content box class { 
     padding-bottom: ;
     margin-bottom: ;

 }
```

}

Comment: Happy to help!
Check the media queries for different sizes / resolution: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you have a php function that return true if [it's mobile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) `wp_is_mobile()` and with that you could put the class that you want in your HTML.

And wordpress add class `.mobile`to your `body`so you could put different padding if have `.mobile` class or not.

Comment: can you explain a bit??

Comment: By default, WP have a function that you can use for mobile, for example, if you can add a class to your HTML code when you are on mobile: `<div class="one <?php if ( wp_is_mobile ) echo 'mobile'; ?>">`. But if you can't use this function, WP, when you are on mobile, add the class `.moble` to your body: `<body class="... mobile">`

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin and padding only if the document is smaller than 500 pixels wide:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .site-content article {
       padding-bottom:0px;
       margin-bottom:0px;
}
```